# Why did moving some variable declarations after OpenGL context init break the code?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm currently working on a Java game and I use OpenGL in an AWT Canvas with LWJGL 2.9.3.
And I actually don't understand why moving some object declarations after `Display.create()` makes the canvas stop showing anything (`glClearColor` still works).

Here is the code that works:

```java
  private void startGL() {
    glThread = new Thread(() -> {
      isRunning = true;

      ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
      Vector3f lightPosition = new Vector3f(-20.0f, 20.0f, -20.0f);
      Matrix4f projMatrix = new Matrix4f();
      Camera camera;
      EntityRenderer entityRenderer = null;

      try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(displayWidth, displayHeight));
        Display.create();
      } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
      glCullFace(GL_BACK);

      camera = new Camera();
      try {
        entityRenderer = new EntityRenderer();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      projMatrix.setPerspective((float) Math.toRadians(45.0f), dmGetAspectRatio(), 0.1f, 1000f);

      while(isRunning) {
         //rendering and update code
      }

      //cleanup code
    }, "LWJGL Thread");

    glThread.start();
  }
```

And here is the code that doesn't work:

```java
  private void startGL() {
    glThread = new Thread(() -> {
      isRunning = true;

      try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(displayWidth, displayHeight));
        Display.create();
      } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
      Vector3f lightPosition = new Vector3f(-20.0f, 20.0f, -20.0f);
      Matrix4f projMatrix = new Matrix4f();
      Camera camera;
      EntityRenderer entityRenderer = null;

      glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
      glCullFace(GL_BACK);

      camera = new Camera();
      try {
        entityRenderer = new EntityRenderer();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      projMatrix.setPerspective((float) Math.toRadians(45.0f), dmGetAspectRatio(), 0.1f, 1000f);

      while(isRunning) {
         //rendering and update code
      }

      //cleanup code
    }, "LWJGL Thread");

    glThread.start();
  }
```

These methods are called by the `addNotify()` method in Canvas initialization.
The complete code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816844/11251801).
This issue is not really important but I would like to know why just the displacement of a few declarations can entirely break the game.

Comment: Yes, you're right it was a timing issue, I've added 20ms sleep before Display.create and works. thank you. and I will also look for the AWTGLCanvas class.